# How to update WCF service APIs in IIS website

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, iis

I am new to WCF Service and IIS. Please help.
**Set up** is mentioned below.

1. I have Entity framework project which deal with Database.
2. Then I have WCF service class library (no app.config file) which writes or read values from EF project.
3. At the end I have website project (ASP.Net Website) which hosts WCF service on IIS (This project has Web.Config file which contains WCF service configuration).
4. In IIS, I created a new application under Default Web Site. When I browse the Service.svc file, I can see all the APIs\methods exposed by WCF service.

Now the problem is, it worked first time. But I want to add new APIs in WCF service, but those APIs are not getting reflected in IIS hosted URL.

### Things I tried

1. Building entire solution.
2. Removing reference of WCF project libraries from website project and reattaching.
3. Building website and publishing website.
4. Reset IIS Manager and refresh everything.

Please help how can I **update the APIs exposed in IIS when update the WCF service**.

Comment: have you looked into this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-iis

Comment: Yes I did. I am able to host properly. The only problem is, when I change anything in WCF project or Entity Framework, it does not reflect in WCF service hosted in IIS.